# html5 canvas elastic collision squares

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, collision

I am re-asking this question since I did not make myself clear in what I wanted in my last question.

Does anyone know how to do elastic collision or handle collision in Canvas using rectangles? Or can point me in the right direction?

I created a canvas that has multiple square and would like each square to deflect when they touch.

Here is a quick fiddle that I put together showing to black buffer canvases http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/Y7MFq/10/

line 39 is where I started the collision detection and line 59 is where I tried to execute it. I will have more than 3 squares moving around and want them to deflect if/when they touch each other

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#FFA500";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var renderToCanvas = function (width, height, renderFunction) {
    var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
    buffer.width = width;
    buffer.height = height;
    renderFunction(buffer.getContext('2d'));
    return buffer;
};

var drawing = renderToCanvas(100, 100, function (ctx) {
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


});

var drawing2 = renderToCanvas(100, 100, function (ctx) {
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


});

var x = 0, 
 y = 0,
x2 = 200,
y2 = 10,
vx = .80,
vy = .80,
vx2 = .80,
vy2 = .80;



    function collides(rectA, rectB) {
      return !(rectA.x + rectA.width < rectB.x2 ||
       rectB.x2 + rectB.width < rectA.x ||
       rectA.y + rectA.height < rectB.y2 ||
       rectB.y2 + rectB.height < rectA.y);
      }; 

    function executeFrame() {
        x+=vx;
        y+=vy;
        x2+=vx2;
        y2+=vy2;

        if( x < 0 || x > 579) vx = -vx; 
        if( y < 0 || y > 265) vy = -vy;

        if( x2 < 0 || x2 > 579) vx2 = - vx2; 
        if( y2 < 0 || y2 > 233) vy2 = - vy2;

        if(collides(drawing, drawing2)){
            //move in different direction
        };

        context.fillStyle = "#FFA500"; 
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(drawing, x, y);
        context.drawImage(drawing2, x2, y2);


        requestAnimationFrame(executeFrame);
    }

    //start animation
    executeFrame();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Rectangular collision detection

To do a rectangular collision detection can be more complicated than it perhaps looks.

It's not just about figuring out if the two rectangles intersects or overlaps, but we also need to know at what angle they collide and what direction they move in order to deflect them properly, ideally transfer "velocity" to each other (mass/energy) and so forth.

This method that I present here will do the following steps:

- First do a simple intersect detection to find out if they collide at all.
- If an intersection: calculate the angle between the two rectangle
- Divide a set primary rectangle into four zones of a circle where zone 1 is right, zone 2 is bottom and so forth.
- Depending on zone, check in what direction the rectangle is moving, if towards the other rectangle deflect it based on which zone was detected.

## ➔ [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Y7MFq/13/)

### ➔ [Version with higher speed here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Y7MFq/14/show/)

### Detect intersection and calculate angle

The code for detecting the intersection and angle is as follows, where `r1` and `r2` are here objects with properties `x`, `y`, `w` and `h`.

```
function collides(r1, r2) {

    /// classic intersection test
    var hit = !(r1.x + r1.w < r2.x ||
               r2.x + r2.w < r1.x ||
               r1.y + r1.h < r2.y ||
               r2.y + r2.h < r1.y);

    /// if intersects, get angle between the two rects to determine hit zone
    if (hit) {
        /// calc angle
        var dx = r2.x - r1.x;
        var dy = r2.y - r1.y;

        /// for simplicity convert radians to degree
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
        if (angle < 0) angle += 360;

        return angle;
        
    } else
        return null;
}
```

This function will return an *angle* or `null` which we then use to determine deflection in our loop (that is: the angle is used to determine the hit zone in our case). This is needed so that they bounce off in the correct direction.

### Why hit zones?

[image: Example scenario]

With just a simple intersection test and deflection you can risk the boxes deflecting like the image on the right, which is not correct for a 2D scenario. You want the boxes to continue in the same direction of where there is no impact as in the left.

### Determine collision zone and directions

Here is how we can determine which velocity vector to reverse (tip: if you want a more *physical* correct deflection you can let the rectangles "absorb" some of the other's velocity but I won't cover that here):

```
var angle = collides({x: x, y: y, w: 100, h: 100},    /// rect 1
                     {x: x2, y: y2, w: 100, h: 100}); /// rect 2

/// did we have an intersection?
if (angle !== null) {

    /// if we're not already in a hit situation, create one
    if (!hit) {
        hit = true;

        /// zone 1 - right
        if ((angle >= 0 && angle < 45) || (angle > 315 && angle < 360)) {
            /// if moving in + direction deflect rect 1 in x direction etc.
            if (vx > 0) vx = -vx;
            if (vx2 < 0) vx2 = -vx2;

        } else if (angle >= 45 && angle < 135) { /// zone 2 - bottom
            if (vy > 0) vy = -vy;
            if (vy2 < 0) vy2 = -vy2;

        } else if (angle >= 135 && angle < 225) { /// zone 3 - left
            if (vx < 0) vx = -vx;
            if (vx2 > 0) vx2 = -vx2;

        } else { /// zone 4 - top
            if (vy < 0) vy = -vy;
            if (vy2 > 0) vy2 = -vy2;
        }
    }
} else
    hit = false;  /// reset hit when this hit is done (angle = null)
```

And that's pretty much it.

The `hit` flag is used so that when we get a hit we are marking the "situation" as a hit situation so we don't get internal deflections (which can happen at high speeds for example). As long as we get an angle after hit is set to true we are still in the same hit situation (in theory anyways). When we receive null we reset and are ready for a new hit situation.

Also worth to mention is that the primary rectangle here (whose side we check against) is the first one (the black in this case).

## More than two rectangles

If you want to throw in more that two rectangle then I would suggest a different approach than used here when it comes to the rectangles themselves. I would recommend creating a [rectangle *object*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338740/simply-canvas-animation/21338879#21338879) which is self-contained in regards to its position, size, color and also embeds methods to update velocity, direction and paint. The rectangle objects could be maintained by a host objects which performs the clearing and calls the objects' update method for example.

To detect collisions you could then iterate the array with these objects to find out which rectangle collided with the current being tested. It's important here that you "mark" (using a flag) a rectangle that has been tested as there will always be at least two in a collision and if you test A and then B you will end up reversing the effect of velocity change without using a flag to skip testing of the collision "partner" object per frame.

## In conclusion

**Note**: there are special cases not covered here such as collision on exact corners, or where a rectangle is trapped between an edge and the other rectangle (you can use the hit flag mentioned above for the edge tests as well).

I have not optimized any of the code but tried to keep it as simple as I can to make it more understandable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I was not aware of the code beyond velocity and hit check needed to accomplish this. This was very detailed eye opener for me. Can you suggest readings that will help me understand the angles better? Also, it's a month since I started to learn Javascript (code in general). Is this something that I should've known or figured out on my own by now?

Comment: @user2856111 if you started a month ago then by no means! It can take a long time (depending on your focus) before this cross your path at this detail level. In that regard my apologies; let me know if you want me to explain some of the code more detailed. Expect to spend 6 months +/- getting acquainted with the language. Then some years to get through all the pitfalls :^) I am unable to recommend a read as I usually don't read any myself. I guess doing this for more than 3 decades has enabled me to solve (most of) these things on my own. Hmm, play around with the arc() method..

Comment: @user2856111 .. That can be a good candidate to challenge yourselves on angles. You can convert between radians (which it uses) and degrees. It will literally illustrate the use of angles, how the angles are positioned in relation to canvas and so forth (ie. 0 degree = right, 90 degrees down etc.).

Comment: Practicing with the arc method sounds like a great idea which I'll put into use. With some playing around I should make more sense of it. Thanks again :) I love getting info beyond my knowledge so this is great for me to study.

Comment: @user2856111 : If you want to know more about doing elastic collisions in JavaScript here is a good tutorial Iv'e found: http://www.adambrookesprojects.co.uk/project/canvas-collision-elastic-collision-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple: swap the velocities of each block when they collide. That's it! Also for your collision test change `RectA.x` to just `x`, since they are normal variables given:

```
    function collides(rectA, rectB) {
      return !(x + rectA.width < x2 ||
       x2 + rectB.width < x ||
       y + rectA.height < y2 ||
       y2 + rectB.height < y);
      };
```

And swapping velocities:

```
        if(collides(drawing, drawing2)){
            var t = vx; var t2 = vy;
            vx = vx2; vy = vy2;
            vx2 = t; vy2 = t2;
        };
```

And after those small changes we have working elastic collisions: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7MFq/11/

Comment: If you see the second collision in the fiddle you posted (http://jsfiddle.net/Y7MFq/11/, ref [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21326180/revisions)) you can see they don't deflect correctly angle-wise. Besides from that, it's a nice and simple way of doing a detection.

Comment: That's because the formula is a 1D based solution, the collisions are correct if they are looked as across a 1D-line. Energy absorption is also applied properly (assuming same mass). I'm aware they don't deflect angle-wise on a 2D plane, but I was going for a very simple solution.

Comment: I would of gave something similar to your answer although the user asked for elastic collisions. So I assumed a basic 1D elastic collision would be more appropriate then a properly deflected 2D collision that is not an elastic collision.

Comment: You could be right about that, personally I assumed 2D due to the fiddle. Lets see if OP can shed some light on this.

Comment: Thanks. I was close to solving the 1D solution in the same way, but I was hoping to achieve 2D results.