# Simply canvas animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a simple canvas animation: two rectangles move in two different directions. However, I feel this could be simplified more.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/R5wx8/6/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    x = 10,
    y = 15,

    a = 20,
    b = 50;

function move() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);

    c.fillRect(0, y, 5, 5),
    c.fillRect(b, 5, 15, 15);


    x++;
    y++;
    b++

    if (y > canvas.height || x > canvas.width) {
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
    }
}

setInterval(move, 100);
```

For example, what happens if I wanted to create another three shapes? At the moment, I'd have to create more variables for each coordinate:

```
    x++;
    y++;
    b++
```

Is there a way I could turn each rectangle into its own object?

Comment: You should consider using [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of setInterval() when animating. Better for performance, and the loop stops when the browser tab is not active. To create a continous loop, replace the setInterval line with `window.requestAnimationFrame(move);` and add the same line again at the beginning of the move function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly turn them into objects, for example:

```
function Rect(x, y, w, h, dltX, dltY, color) {

    var me = this;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;

    this.deltaX = dltX || 0;       /// and deltas can be optional
    this.deltaY = dltY || 0;
    this.color = color || '#000';  /// color is optional
    
    this.update = function(ctx) {
        me.x += me.deltaX;
        me.y += me.deltaY;
        
        ctx.fillStyle = me.color;
        ctx.fillRect(me.x, me.y, me.width, me.height);
    }    
}
```

The `deltaX` and `deltaY` are how much you want to move the rectangle for each update. If you set these to for example 1 then `x` and `y` will be increased with 1 each time `update()` is called.

Using deltas makes it easy to create bounces (see demo below) by simply reversing the delta value (ie. `delta = -delta`) as well as things such as acceleration, variate speed, you can feed them through trigonometric functions to have the object move in a specific angle and so forth.

You can used fixed values if you desire but you will discover that deltas are beneficial in the long run (ref. comment: it's actually a very classic method used in for instance the first Pong games :-) ).

## [Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Ybrtc/)

Now that we have defined the object we can simply create instances of it and store them in an array:

```
var rects = [
    new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100, 1, -2),
    new Rect(100, 1, 50, 50, 2, 1, '#f00'),
    ...
]
```

From here it's simply a matter of iterating the array to update each object:

```
function move() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for(var i = 0, r; r = rects[i]; i++) {
        /// check any conditions here
        r.update(ctx);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
}

requestAnimationFrame(move); /// start loop
```

Comment: I have never seen that for loop syntax before, and it's awesome. Using the assignment as an array bounds check, brilliant.

Comment: Could you explain the deltaX, deltaY? I've not seen that before.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why you've declared`var me = this;`, but then only used it in an update function? I'm still trying to get my head around this.

Comment: @tmyie call it a habit from making more complex objects where caller scope is changed and this becomes needed. You would need a reference to "this" scope but as "this" could change it would not refer to the intended object. For the use here you will probably not need it so it can be ignored (replaced).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to create a very simple object compared to yours, but it draws nothing. Could you say where it goes wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/Spp3s/

Comment: @Tesserex it's pretty neat. You can make it even shorter: `for(var i = 0, r; r = rects[i++];)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly simpler version, though in the long term I'd recommend Ken's. In mine the rects are still just property bags, with no behavior on their own.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rects = [{x:0, y:15, w:5, h:5, vx:0, vy:1},
             {x:50, y:5, w:15, h:15, vx:1, vy:0}];

function move() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);

    for (var i=0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        var rect = rects[i];
        c.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h),
        rect.x += rect.vx;
        rect.y += rect.vy;
    }
}

setInterval(move, 100);
```