# setInterval on group of objects in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, setinterval

Hello :) I spent many hours on figuring out how to implement my code. I have group of objects (random rectangles) in array. I want to make them move at the same time like an one object from left to right and from right to left. But before everything I dont know how make them move as one object.... Any help will appreciated. Thank you.

```
<html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <title>Canvas Demo</title>
           <script>
               window.onload = function () {

                      function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
}

// get canvas element.
var elem = document.getElementById('paper');

// check if context exist
if (elem.getContext) {

    var myRect = [];

    myRect.push(new Shape(10, 0, 25, 25, "#333"));
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 40, 39, 25, "#333"));
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 80, 100, 25, "#333"));

    context = elem.getContext('2d');
    for (var i in myRect) {
        oRec = myRect[i];
        context.fillStyle = oRec.fill;
        context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);

    }

}
 var posX= 0;
                      setInterval( function(){



                            posX +=1;
        oRec = myRect[i];
        context.fillStyle = oRec.fill;
        context.fillRect(oRec.posX, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);
}, 40); };

           </script>
           <style>
           </style>
       </head>


       <body>
           <canvas id="paper" width="500" height="500">
           </canvas>
       </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the property on the object itself. Right now you are updating posX which is not attached to any of the objects. Try with for example:

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/KsqG7/)

```
setInterval( function(){

    /// clear canvas for each frame
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

    /// iterate object array and move all objects
    for(var i = 0, oRec; oRec = myRect[i]; i++) {
        oRec.x++;  /// update each object's position
        context.fillStyle = oRec.fill;
        context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);
    }
}, 40);
```

You should also consider iterating your array with a counter and not use key (which is slow) as shown here. The first loop block right after your array push()'es is not necessary and can be removed.

I would also recommend you to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval()`.

**[Here's a version](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/KsqG7/1/)** using rAF (for completeness).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will change setInterval on requestAnimationFrame. Also my rectangles disappear somewhere out of canvas. I can make if condition so that rectangles go to right side of canvas until some coordinates and go back from right side to left side, right? P.S. I am new to canvas, sorry. @Ken

Comment: @user3247903 no problem, we're here to help! A condition should do the trick. You can use a delta value as well if you want to toggle the direction. See if this answer can help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338740/simply-canvas-animation/21338879#21338879

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you wanna animate.

Anyway i changed a little your code:

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
}
var elem=document.getElementById('paper'),myRect=[],context,posX=0;
if(elem.getContext){
 myRect.push(new Shape(10, 0, 25, 25, "#333"));
 myRect.push(new Shape(0, 40, 39, 25, "#333"));
 myRect.push(new Shape(0, 80, 100, 25, "#333"));
 context=elem.getContext('2d');
}
function animate(){
 context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
 posX++;
 var i=myRect.length;
 while(i--){
  var oRec=myRect[i];
  context.fillStyle=oRec.fill;
  context.fillRect(oRec.x+posX, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);
 }
 webkitRequestAnimationFrame(animate);//delete if you use setinterval
}
//setInterval(animate,1000);
webkitRequestAnimationFrame(animate);//delete if you use setinterval
```

As you can see i'm using `requestAnimationFrame`. that's **better than** `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.
I also created a custom function to animate the stuff.. which u can change with whatever you want.

if you have any questions just ask.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/SqDx9/1/

btw if you don't animate more than 100 shapes you should use css ... it's simpler.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/4eujG/